# Send data to the server whithout affecting the UI cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I am working on a cordova project using angular JS. In our app we will store the transactions in the SQLite DB when the app is offline and will send the data to the server once the device came online. While sending the data to the server, the user should able to access the UI. That means the data should be send in a separate thread. Is it possible to do in Javascript/angular JS? If so how to do it?